# Get cell format from Google Spreadsheet (app script or formula)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help.

I need to calculate the amount in different currencies from the General list. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Clear formatting on E:E. Do they all align on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to separate add another column.
- 1 column should be for USD
- 1 column should be for RUB

Then you summarize them using the SUMIF Formula, for example to calculate the sum of Bred, assuming column E contains the USD amount:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E, B:B, "Bred")
```

Then to calculate the RUB, assuming column F contains the RUB amount:

```
=SUMIFS(F:F, B:B, "Bred")
```

Comment: This option is not suitable, you need to count from one column.

Comment: Then you need to convert it to either RUB or USD. For that, add a field anywhere which contains the exchange rate and use it to calculate the fields.

Comment: Why can't I find out what currency is set in a cell? It's simple.

Comment: You would need an extra column to hold that particular information. But again, the answer provided originally serves your purpose and allows maximum flexibility in the future. It only costs one extra column and columns cost 0 USD and 0 RUB, so use them freely.

Comment: Two additional columns. 1 - price per piece, 2-total amount. I thought that you can find out what currency is in the cell and count rubles or dollars depending on it. The question is closed. All thanks.